# Enumerating types for a given column for a model object

Tags: compoundjs, railway.js, jugglingdb

I have an obect called "Task" and each task has a type. In my database design without ORM, i would have a table called TaskTypes and Task table would have foreign key to the TaskTypes table where we define Tasks..

Is there a way to handle this behaviour natively in jugglingdb? Or do i have to create another model called TaskTypes and make Task "belongTo" a TaskType class?

Answer (score 0):

The "native" way to handle this would be to define each model.

You can take a slight shortcut with `Task.belongsTo('tasktype');` which will add the column `tasktypeId` for you.